# What is the difference between using a struct with two fields and a pair?

Tags: c++, struct, std, std-pair

What is the difference regarding memory allocation and efficiency between using a struct with two fields and a pair?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`std::pair` provides pre-written constructors and comparison operators.  This also allows them to be stored in containers like std::map without you needing to write, for example, the copy constructor or strict weak ordering via `operator <` (such as required by `std::map`).  If you don't write them you can't make a mistake (remember how strict weak ordering works?) so it's more reliable just to use `std::pair`.

Comment: I don't think std::pair provides any constructors or operators for its members. What exactly are you thinking of?

Comment: @Manuel, actually I just checked and sure enough, `pair` provides a default ctor, and a template copy ctor.  Makes sense -- this way, in each case, `pair` allows calling it if & only if the underlying types allow it.

Comment: Yes but the OP seemed to be implying that std::pair *magically* generated those members for the underlying types. It's weird that this answer is the one that got accepted.

Comment: The wording could have been a little better but I do think AshleysBrain knows what (s)he's talking about.

Comment: Edited to try and clarify the wording.

Comment: I think this warrants a mentioning of `std::make_pair()`, which is rather convenient in many circumstances, especially so in connection with the new meaning of `auto`.

Comment: Does the fact std::pair has a constructor make it a little bit slower than a struct without constructor? if we add millions of items to a std::map for example ?

Answer (score 23):

`std::pair` comes with a number of constructors and operators.

A `struct` allow named fields (other than `first` and `second`) and is ready to be extended at any time.

Prefer a `struct` when you can. It may involve some overhead, but is definitely easier for maintenance.

Comment: +1 for the maintenance comment. I worked with a group of engineers from NJ who tried to do everything (and I mean everything) with the STL, and rather than creating appropriate classes/structs when the design indicated, they used an STL container. Code was littered with "if (route.first.second[*iter].first) { ... }". Ugh!

Answer (score 7):

In terms of memory allocation and efficiency, there is no difference -- since that's exactly what a `std::pair` is.

Comment: That is what answers what I was wondering about, I suddenly realized that efficiency really depends on what you would do so is a bit too much information. I'm going to accept AshleysBrain's question for thinking further...

Comment: No problem, but it would have made more sense to ask about comparing ease-of-use if that's what you're interested in. Naveen and I both answered the question as stated. (Not complaining, just saying...)

Comment: Hmm, seem to have made a serious typo in my comment. "That is the answer I was wondering about" it should have been. I gave AshleysBrain the accepted answer as he was was quick and gave a good answer, just like you. It was hard to choose, but I went for the one who would benefit most.

Comment: Is there a source file / header showing that a pair is coded internally as a struct ?

Comment: @Basj: I don't have the C++09 standard on hand, but I believe this is required by the standard.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: If you find the C++09 standard, let me know ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Whoops, obviously that should have been "C++11".

Answer (score 2):

No difference in terms of memory allocation or efficiency.  In fact, in the STL implementation I am using pair is defined as `struct pair`

Comment: What STL implementation are you using ?

Comment: I am using the one which comes with VC9 compiler.

Comment: Yes, this adheres to the common convention that if a user-defined type exposes public data members (like `pair` does with `first` and `second`) then it has to be a `struct`.

Comment: Could be a `class` with `first` and `second` declared in a `public` section.  According to the interface, the `first` and `second` members must be public; doesn't state whether it must be a `class` or `struct`.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews: There is no semantic difference whatsoever between `struct X { ... };` and `class X { public: ... };`.  (Unlike in C# for example.)

Comment: This seems to be in contradiction with Basj's answer.

Answer (score 2):

As this isn't mentioned above, if you want the benefits of your own name, but the advantages of std::pair (or any other objects), you can use "using" ( from c++11 onwards). You can set this in your namespace or class declaration.

In fact this is how many of my classes now start out...

```
using myPair = pair<int,string>;
```

cf. [C++ reference. for more documentation.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)

Comment: While true, this still has the `.first` and `.second` "problem".

Comment: @infinitezero - that's correct. It's when I start seeing first.second.first, or needing to add functions, that I know it's time to turn the alias into a struct.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [std::pair<int, int> vs struct with two int's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606894/stdpairint-int-vs-struct-with-two-ints) a struct will probably be a little bit faster because no initialization is made.