# struct with 2 cells vs std::pair?

Tags: c++, struct, std-pair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between using a struct with two fields and a pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236182/what-is-the-difference-between-using-a-struct-with-two-fields-and-a-pair)

Dear all,

I have a little question about pairs and struct. Is there any advantage to use a std::pair instead of a struct with two cells ?
I have used pairs for a while but the main problem is readability :
If you want to represent for example a duple (int "label", double "value") you can use either a  :

```
typedef std::pair<int,double> myElem;
```

or a

```
typedef struct {
    int label;
    double value;
} myElem;
```

The code becomes more readable if your statements have a "semantic" sense (you will always know what x.label is. that's not the case with x.first).

However, I guess there is an advantage using pair. Is it more performant or something else?

Comment: @KennyTM: Yes, sorry. I missed this topic during my search.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `pair` is implemented as a templated `struct`. It provides you with a shorthand for creating a (typically heterogenous) pair. Also, there are some constraints on the types that you can use with a `pair`:

> **Type requirements**
>
> T1 and T2 must both
>   be models of Assignable. Additional
>   operations have additional
>   requirements. Pair's default
>   constructor may only be used if both
>   T1 and T2 are DefaultConstructible,
>   operator== may only be used if both T1
>   and T2 are EqualityComparable, and
>   operator< may only be used if both T1
>   and T2 are LessThanComparable.

(from SGI STL [`std::pair`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/pair.html) documentation)

Defining your own POD may make sense if the types do not follow any of these constraints or if you do not care about them.

Finally, I guess it is a matter of personal choice/coding style.

Answer (score 33):

In terms of performance: it's unlikely to change anything, you're just sugar coating it.

In terms of usability, I would rather use a custom struct, which can be declared this way (by the way):

```
struct MyElement
{
  int label;
  double value;
};
```

I am a strong proponent of strong typing, and I much prefer a "real" structure (and better yet, class) than an ad-hoc tuple whenever it's more than a fleeting thing.

Mainly because:

- As you noted `first` and `second` don't carry much meaning
- You cannot add methods / other fields to a `std::pair`
- You cannot add class invariants to a `std::pair`

All in all, I really think that maintenance benefits from using a custom dedicated structure that a one-size-fits-them-all tuple.

Answer (score 7):

Its primary advantage is that it's generic. For example, when you retrieve something from an `std::map`, you get the key and the associated value as the first and second items in an `std::pair`.

Likewise, when you use `std::equal_range` to find a set of equal values in a collection, you get iterators to the beginning and end of the range as the first and second items in an `std::pair`.

It's hard to imagine meaningful labels that would apply to both of these, so they settled for a couple that don't mean very much, but at least aren't misleading. Using 'key' and 'data' would work for `std::map`, but be misleading for `std::equal_range` (and if you switched to something like `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` to make them more meaningful for `std::equal_range`, it'd be equally wrong for items in `std::map`).

Comment: Just my opinion, but I don't like the choice they made.  a map-entry should have been (key,value) and a range should have been (begin, end).  Now, we are stuck with having to use the meaningless and misleading (first, second) in both cases.  And it is difficult and not-idiomic to change the field-names.

Answer (score 6):

> However, I guess there is an advantage using pair. Is it more performant or something else?

I doubt it, an instantiated `std::pair` is just a `struct`, after all. `std::pair` comes with `operator<` defined, though. But that shouldn't be too hard to do yourself for a `struct` with only two members.

So I usually do as you reasoned: a `struct` with dedicated member names is easier to read than `first` and `second`.

Answer (score 4):

With a std::pair, you are free to use functors from the STL such as select1st or select2nd. Likewise it allows you to use other generic functions with your pair, such as operator< and others. Admittedly, with the advent of boost/tr1, you could achieve much the same effect by using bind.

Your point about readability is very true though.