# When is it good to use std::pair?

Tags: c++, coding-style, std-pair

My impression is that it is always better to define my own struct, such that I can use meaningful field names instead of `first` and `second`.

One place where the standard uses `std::pair` is for accessing elements of `std::map`. `first` is the key, and `second` the value. Would not it be much better to have a specific `key_value_pair` template, and refer to its fields as `key` and `value` instead of `first` and `second`? It seems to me that it would make code considerably more readable at no cost.

Comment: But there *is* a cost! More code. Repeated bugs all over the place. Slightly different design choices every time. If you just want to store two values, what is wrong with `std::pair`? If you have a type, with some meaning, and some member functions, that just happens to have two data members, fine, write your own `class`. But for a pair of objects, why not call it `pair`?

Comment: I found this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236182/what-is-the-difference-between-using-a-struct-with-two-fields-and-a-pair?lq=1 . That still is not enough motivation for me to use `std::pair`. But I guess that is a matter of personal taste.

Comment: @Rémi: the question could be generalized to `std::tuple`.

Comment: Another similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607352/struct-with-2-cells-vs-stdpair?rq=1 . Still I am not convinced by any of the answer that std::pair might be useful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I generally use pairs (and tuples) when I need a local package of 2 or more objects.

The primary usecase is for the return type of a function: C++ does not allow returning multiple values, but allows returning a structure with multiple fields. Rather than use output parameters, I prefer using a pair or tuple.

The second usecase is for ad-hoc storage of elements; for example to automagically generate `operator<` for

```
struct A { int a; int b; int c; };
```

You can write `operator<` this way:

```
bool operator<(A const& left, A const& right) {
    return std::tie(left.a , left.b , left.c )
         < std::tie(right.a, right.b, right.c);
}
```

it automagically generates a correct lexicographical order (so many people screw up those operators...).

Comment: Thanks. It is not really related to my question, but I am glad to learn that `std::tie` exists. The ready-made `operator<` might be useful indeed. In situations where using `first` and `second` does not hurt readability, using a pair might be convenient. But I really hate using `first` and `second` for maps.

Comment: This works for a host of boilerplate methods: adding `make_tie` methods reduces `=` `==` `<` and `swap` to a O(1) code, and isolates bugs in `make_tie` where they can be universal rather than hidden in a corner case.

Comment: @Rémi: oh, I definitely agree with your point about `map`; here `.key` and `.value` would be much better!