# Using templates like std::pair, std::tuple vs creating structs for holding two values, which one is better in terms of compile time performance?

Tags: c++, templates, struct

```
std::map<double, std::pair<int, int>> templates;
```

this is the variable I declared to hold temporary values while performing some operation.

if I declared this as

```
struct TemplateIndex
{
  int i,
  int j
}; 

std::map<double, TemplateIndex> templates;
```

would this increase compile time performance?, any advantages or disadvantages?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between using a struct with two fields and a pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236182/what-is-the-difference-between-using-a-struct-with-two-fields-and-a-pair)

Comment: Relateed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3607745/12416453

Comment: @Ch3steR no they haven't discussed about compile time performance

Comment: If it means you can `#include` less standard headers in your code, it could probably speed up compilation time. My guess is that the difference would be very small though. If compilation time is that important, you probably have a fairly big code-base that you could try on and see.

Comment: Note: using `double`/`float` as key is "dangerous" (rounding, ...).

Answer (score 0):

In GNU libstdc++ std::pair is a template-based struct with two elements.
Look here:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.3/a02030.html

So I don't think there is much a difference.,

Answer (score 0):

`std::pair` is evaluated at compile time while your defined struct is not evaluated at compile time, so talking about performance `std::pair` is more way better. So `std::pair` will prevent the program from being constructed if there's an error.

if you want to use your defined struct at compile time you have to use  a templated struct.

N.B.: using template and now in C++20 we talk about concept is a good programming practice.

Answer (score 0):

As always for performance, you have to measure:

That [benchmark](https://build-bench.com/b/qGCXFEDmA40E7uazC2PPtHXVrSQ) shows similar result.

Especially `std::map` already uses `std::pair`, so you don't even avoid the corresponding include in that case.

I would go for the more readable/expressive.