# Why would i use a UTILITY as opposed to a STRUCT?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between using a struct with two fields and a pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236182/what-is-the-difference-between-using-a-struct-with-two-fields-and-a-pair)

I been looking through a c++ quick reference app and noticed the UTILITY data structure `pair< TypeName, TypeName>` to store a pair of variables in what i would think a struct. I'm confused on why this would be implemented as opposed to just using a simple struct, could someone enlighten me on why pair might be of any use?

```
pair<string, int> a("hello",3); // A 2-element struct
a.first;  //"hello"
a.second; //3
```

I would think using a struct would be a better practice, as you can look back on the struct type and create objects of that specific struct while `pair` could be prone to simple mistakes if multiple copies were needed.

```
struct Data
{
    string str;
    int num;
}

Data pair1;
pair1.str = "hello";
pair1.num = 3;
```

Comment: Child reinvents wheel. Scientists baffled.

Comment: My apologies, i searched the forums for a question similar to this but obviously used the wrong keywords.

Comment: C++ does not have anything called an `UTILITY`, or for that matter, a `STRUCT`. It does have a thing called a `struct` (note, C++ is case sensitive). And it has a class template called `pair` (or, if you want to be explicit, `std::pair`), which exists in a header named `utiity` (again, case sensitive). You'll make everyone's lives much easier if you refer to things by their names. ;)