# The choice between sdt::pair and struct in c++

Tags: c++, performance, memory, android-ndk

I'm newbie in c++ and try to implement a native library for my android app to encode and decode audio using NDK and FFmpeg, during the implementation process I noticed that I quite often use pointers to `std::pair<uint_8t *, int>` to storing audio samples data and data length in it.

Also i can create a struct with the same types of variables that my pair has and use this struct instead of the pairs, but since I don't have much knowledge in c++ I'd like to know which type is more suitable in my work, which is more fast and has low memory usage and also might there are more effective types in c++ that i don't know?

As for my native library it just encodes/decodes and resamples audio and it doesn't have async functions, threads and so on and executes in the same thread that called it's methods from java/kotlin layer.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2236182/4389800

Comment: `std::pair` is a `struct` containing two members. The only practical difference of defining your own `struct` type to hold two associated values is that the members can have any name your like, rather than `first` and `second`. Also, why are you using pointers to `std::pair` instead of standard containers  or (if you are creating a single instance of pair) simply using variables of automatic storage duration? It seems you are coding in C++ like you would in Java, despite them being very different languages, and constructs that look the same behaving differently.

Comment: @Peter I use pointers to std::pair because I didn't find more effective way to return null from a method in case of the result doesn't have data or should I just return an empty pair with null data and zero length of data?

Comment: C++11 and later, look up `std::optional`