# Does the default constructor of std::pair<> set basic types (int, etc) to zero?

Tags: c++

After writing:

```
std::pair<int, int> x;
```

Am I guaranteed that x.first and x.second are both zero?  Or could they have any value?

The reason why I care is because I'm trying to determine whether a map whose values are pointers is guaranteed to return NULL if I access an element that's not in the map.  I.e., if I do:

```
std::map<int, void*> my_map;
std::cout << int(my_map[5]) << std::endl;
```

then am I guaranteed to get zero (NULL)?  Or is the behavior undefined?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606894/stdpairint-int-vs-struct-with-two-ints

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, that guarantee holds true. Quoting the C++11 standard, §20.3.2/2-3:

> `constexpr pair();`
>
> 2 *Requires:* `is_default_constructible<first_type>::value` is `true` and `is_default_constructible<second_type>::value` is `true`.
>   3 *Effects:* Value-initializes `first` and `second`.

And §8.5/7:

> To *value-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type with a user-provided constructor, then the default constructor for `T` is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if `T` has no accessible default constructor);
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and, if `T`'s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is called.
> - if `T` is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
> - **otherwise, the object is zero-initialized**.

And lastly, §8.5/5:

> To *zero-initialize* an object or reference of type `T` means:
>
> - **if `T` is a scalar type, the object is set to the value `0` (zero), taken as an integral constant expression, converted to `T`**;
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, each non-static data member and each base-class subobject is zero-initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) union type, the object’s first non-static named data member is zero-initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;
> - if `T` is an array type, each element is zero-initialized;
> - if `T` is a reference type, no initialization is performed.

Comment: The default constructor of int is to set it to zero?

Comment: @André : `int` doesn't have a default constructor, and default-initializing an `int` would leave its value undefined. What's being used here is _value-initialization_.

Answer (score 6):

From C++11 standard, section *§ 20.3.2*

```
constexpr pair();
...
Effects: Value-initializes first and second.
```

So it is well-defined that the default initialization of an `std::pair<int, int>` object will result in both members being set to 0.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are zero-initialized. A citation of Bjarne Stroustrup's "The C++ Programming Language" (3rd edn, Ch. 17.4.1.7):

> The result of `m[k]` is equivalent to the result of `(*(m.insert(make_pair(k,V())).first)).second`, where `V()` is the default value of the mapped type. When you understand that equivalence, you probably understand associative containers.

For standard citations what default-initialized means look at the others answers.

Comment: That citation seems to pertain to the behavior of `std::map<>::operator[]`, not to the behavior of default-constructing a `std::pair<>`.

Comment: @ildjarn: Correct. In Stroustrup's text `m` is a `std::map<KeyType,V>`. The pair is build and inserted to the map when accessing a non-existing key, like done in the second part of the OP's question.

Comment: Ah, somehow I entirely overlooked the OP's use of `std::map<>`. +1 for paying attention. :-P

Comment: IMHO there is a typo—`m[k]` is equivalent to `m.insert(std::make_pair(k, V())).first->second`.

Comment: @Eli4ph: Indeed the German edition left out a pair of parentheses, leading to syntac error. The English book version has it syntactically correct. Thanks!