# map operator [] and bool as value

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

We know that if we try to access a nonexistent key of `std::map` with the operator [] , the function will insert a new element with that key.

We have: `std::map<std::string, bool> map_xxx;`

Is it guaranteed that after accessing the nonexistent key of `map_xxx["nonexistent_key"]`, the value of the second argument will always be `false` ?

ps. if no, any ideas how to have this behavior?

Comment: I think your question is really: "What is the value of `bool()`?", as evident from the code shown on [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does the default constructor of std::pair<> set basic types (int, etc) to zero?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025792/does-the-default-constructor-of-stdpair-set-basic-types-int-etc-to-zero)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Yes.  The value to be inserted is guaranteed to be `false`.**

---

In C++98, the mechanism was called default initialization, specified as zero initialization for non-classes; that's `false` for Booleans.

Since C++03, the mechanism is called value initialization, still specified as zero initialization for non-classes; and thus still `false` for Booleans.  For example, let's see what C++14 has to say on this.

From §23.4.4.3; just substitute `bool` for "T".

> **T**& operator[](const key_type& x);
>
> 1. Effects: If there is no key equivalent to x in the map, inserts value_type(x, **T()**) into the map.
> 2. Requires: key_type shall be CopyInsertable and mapped_type shall be DefaultInsertable into
>      *this.

From §8.5, digest the paragraphs from the bottom up:

> To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:
>
> — if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is initialized to the value obtained by **converting** the integer literal **0** (zero) to T;
>
> ...
>
> To **value-initialize** an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with either no default constructor (12.1) or a default constructor that is user-provided or deleted, then the object is default-initialized;
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and the semantic constraints for default-initialization are checked, and if T has a non-trivial default constructor, the object is default-initialized;
>
> — if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
>
> — otherwise, the object is **zero-initialized**.
>
> ...
>
> An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., **()**, shall be **value-initialized**.

From §4.12:

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. A **zero value**, null pointer value, or null member pointer value **is converted to false**; any other value is converted to true. For direct-initialization (8.5), a prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be converted to a prvalue of type bool; the resulting value is false.