# Where is defined that int() is 0?

Tags: c++, standards

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::pair<std::string, int> s;
    std::cout << s.second << std::endl;
}
```

In this example `s.second` is `0` though it is not initialized. Can you provide a link to C++ standard where is defined why is it `0`. I know it is because `s.second` is initialized by `int()`, but cant found the line in standard where is stated that `int()` is `0`.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025792/does-the-default-constructor-of-stdpair-set-basic-types-int-etc-to-zero

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's

#### 8.5 Initializers [dcl.init]

> 10) An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be value-initialized.

and

> 7) To value-initialize an object of type T means: 
>   — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor (12.1), then the
>   default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default
>   constructor);
>   — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object
>   is zero-initialized and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is
>   called.
>   — if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
>   **— otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.**

and I guess

> 5) To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:
>   — if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value 0 (zero), taken as an integral constant expression,
>   converted to T; [...]

Comment: But where does it say that a value-initialized int == 0?

Comment: @mfontanini added relevant section.

Comment: @mfontanini also added where zero-initialized actually means 0. :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore can you provide a link to standard file which you use. I didnt find 7) part here http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf

Comment: @Ashot: I provided a link to a more recent draft in my answer (the original ISO Standard is not free of charge).

Comment: @Ashot it's still in 8.5, under different wording.

Comment: Thank you LuchianGrigore, I have already found it.

Answer (score 5):

> I know it is because s.second is initialized by int(), but cant found the line in standard where is stated that int() is 0.

Here is the path you have to follow in the C++11 Standard - this answer uses [Draft n3485](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) as a reference, which is more recent than the current official Standard.

Per Paragraph 8.5/11 of the C++11 Standard:

> An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be **value-initialized**. [...]

Moreover, per Paragraph 8.5/8 of the C++11 Standard:

> To **value-initialize** an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with either no default constructor (12.1) or a
>   default constructor that is user-provided or deleted, then the object is default-initialized;
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided or deleted default constructor,
>   then the object is zero-initialized and, if T has a non-trivial default constructor, default-initialized;
>
> — if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
>
> — **otherwise, the object is zero-initialized**.

Finally (although this is quite intuitive), per Paragraph 8.5/6:

> To **zero-initialize** an object or reference of type T means:
>
> — **if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value 0 (zero)**, taken as an integral constant expression, converted to T;
>
> — [...]

Answer (score 3):

> I know it is because s.second is initialized by int()

The standard doesn't actually say that `second` is initialized with `int()`. It just gives the effect of creating a `std::pair` with the default constructor as (§20.3.2):

> *Effects*: Value-initializes first and second.

Value-initialization is defined as (§8.5):

> To *value-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) [...]
> - if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type [...]
> - if `T` is an array type, [...]
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

Whcih results in `second` being zero-initialized because it is an `int` (§8.5):

> To *zero-initialize* an object or reference of type `T` means:
>
> - if `T` is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value 0 (zero), taken as an integral constant expression, converted to T;
> - [...]