# How does std::map make sure all pointers are null?

Tags: c++, stl, std, stdmap

I'm implementing a custom map class similar to the one from std, however I have one problem.In their map, when you do(for instance):

```
map<string, SomeObject*> container;
SomeObject* object = container["this doesn't exist"];
```

in the debugger object is **0x0000000**, so invalid values from map are always null.However, in my map invalid values are like uninitialized pointers - they have an invalid value like **0xcdcdcdcd**, however in Release mode its something else, so I cant rely to check for

```
if(object == 0xcdcdcdcd)
```

So I would like to be able to do this:

```
MyMap<string, SomeObject*> container;
SomeObject* object = container["this doesn't exist"]; //and for this to definetely be nullptr
```

so I can then do

```
if(object == nullptr)
   DoSomething();
```

I have a **bool ContainsKey(KeyType key);** function, but it involves a for loop.Is there some way to ensure what I want in initialization-time for the map, or do I have to make a custom **PointerWrapper** that will contain a pointer of **SomeObject** that is set to **nullptr** in **PointerWrapper**'s constructor?I had a hard time figuring out what is going on in the std headers, they have an enormous amount of macros and typedefs.

Comment: `std::map<>` _value-initializes_ its values – see [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9025792/636019) for standardese.

Comment: The typical way to check for a key is map::find(key)!=map::end, rather than checking for default value. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333728/stdmap-default-value has an ok solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your values (**for any type**) will be initialized if you *explicitly construct* the object

```
SomeObject* object = SomeObject*();
//                              ^^ Explicit construction
```

For classes, the default constructor is obviously being called.

For built-in types like `int`s and pointers (like `SomeObject*`), they will be zero-initialized (instead of uninitialized)

So, whileyou could use `= NULL` in your specific pointer example, syntax like this will do The Right Thing for **all types**.

```
template < typename Key, typename Value >
void MyMap<Key, Value> add_new_key( const Key &k )
{
   std::pair<Key, Value>( k, Value() );
//                                ^^ Either calls constructor or zero-initializes

   // Store the data as you wish...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::map` value initializes any new values it creates internally. In the case of scalar types, this means they get initialized to 0.

Answer (score 2):

with std::map when you refer to an entry that doesnt exist it creates one and sets its value to be empty. For a pointer that means setting the value to null;